# Create filter for a specific object in QLikview

Tags: qlikview

Plz, can we create filter for a specific object in Qlikview?

I have a lot of object: chart, table .... and I want to create a new table and filter specific for this table.

I need your help, 
Thank you
regards

Comment: Please provide some part of your code, and create minimal problem for better understanding what you are asking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the associative model nature of QV you can't bind specific filter with specific objects. One way to simulate this is to use Alternate States. You can find a lot of info about them around.

You can check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h4yaGA-NTLA) for more info.

There is working example shipped with your QV install:

`C:\Program Files\QlikView\Examples\Documents\Whats New in QlikView11.qvw` and check `Product Grouping` tab